# What is needed to build and distribute custom iOS app for specific client?

Tags: ios, flutter

I never developed any app for apple device so please bear with me.

So far, I've been publishing an app for Android devices. Typically, I would generate an "Ad-hoc" .apk file with a certificate I created, then send the .apk file to the client and their IT department deployed the application.

I done some research but need verification from someone that is familiar with this process.
Does it look like that?:

```
1. Create app for example in Flutter.
2. Generate ipa file. Should I do it in "Ad-hoc" distribution and do I need Apple Developer or Apple Enterprise Developer account?
3. I send ipa file to tester via TestFlight
3. After application is approved by client I send ipa file via diawi or email.
4. Client use Apple Business Manager to send it to all devices.
5. Done?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who owns the code? You or the client. It sounds like it is you.

In this case you need to do the following:

1. Get an Apple Developer programme membership in your/your companies name.
2. Develop the app.
3. Create an app record in App Store Connect. Set its availability as a "custom app" and add  your client's Apple Business Manager ID.
4. Distribute the build to App Store Connect.
5. Have them test with TestFlight (optional).
6. Submit to Apple Review.
7. When approved, your client can obtain the app via Apple Business Manager and distribute it to their employees.

There is no need for ad-hoc builds or Diawi.

Answer (score 0):

Default steps to send iOS app for testing and distribution:

1. Client should have Apple Developer Account (App Store Developer Account) and add you as Developer. That will make you have access to App Store Connect, test app locally by XCode and upload builds to TestFlight.
2. You upload builds to TestFlight (e.g. directly from XCode). Client (or/and testers) can check it on their iOS devices.
3. You or client promote app from testing to production.

Comment: Do I need access to App Store Connect even if this app shouldn't be avaible in App Store publicly? This app is only for internal company use.